# Why does $_GET always returns null even if the data is successfully sent through AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am writing a PHP script to dynamically Create table in Mysql based  upon users' input for number of rows and columns.
I am using AJAX to send the data to the server. In-spite of successful   sending, server is receiving null values in $_GET array.

Here is my entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>

<style type="text/css">
    #head-text{
    text-align: center;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 250%;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="head-text">Snippt</h1>
    <div class="main-content">

    <frameset>
        <form>
        <select name="n-cols" id="n-cols"  onchange="createInputFields()">
            <option>Number of columns</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <div id="main">

    </div>

    <div id="display">

    </div>

</frameset>

</div>
</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function createInputFields(){

    var x = document.getElementById('n-cols');
    var n = x.value;

    if(x.selectedIndex == 0){
        alert('Choose a valid index');
    }
    //adding the input fields based on user's input

    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML ='<br>';
    for(var i = 0; i < n;i++){
        var field_name = "text" + i;
        //alert(field_name);
        document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += '<input     type="text" name = "col" placeholder="column name"> &nbsp;&nbsp; <select>  <option>Integer</option> <option>Varchar</option>  </select><br> <br> ';
    }



            document.getElementById('main').innerHTML+='<input type="submit" onClick="createTable('+ n +')" Value="Create Table">';

}


function createTable(n){

    var column_names = [];

    for(var i=0;i<n;i++){   
        var column_name = document.getElementsByName('col')[i].value;
        column_names.push(column_name);
    }

    /*
    Sending the column_names array to PHP file residing on the server
    */
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }


    var column_names_json = JSON.stringify(column_names);
    //alert(column_names_json);
    xmlhttp.open("GET","create_table.php?col_name = "+column_names_json,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    alert('data sent');
}

</script>
</html>
```

create_table.php

```
<?php

$arr_json = $_GET['col_name'];
$arr = json_decode($arr_json);

for($x = 0; $x< count($arr); $x++){
    echo $arr[$x];
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

When i am printing the content of $_GET, it returns NULL.

Comment: Add `print_r($_GET);` to the PHP to see if there is anything in the array

Comment: I did that : It shows --  Undefined index: col_name...It seems that the null array is creating all the problems!! @JayBlanchard

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Yes there is nothing wrong with AJAX..
I've checked in developer tools and the array is being sent without any problems.
No error is being reported.
And i am using lampp server!

Comment: So - the array is being sent, but it is not in `$_GET`. Have you checked `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: Yeah it returned the same result!
I am preety much sure that there is something wrong with this part :

$arr=isset($_GET['col_name']) ? json_decode($_GET['col_name']) : Array();
print_r($arr);

I am getting Array() as output on the browser...

Comment: That tells you the array is not in `$_GET`. Do `print_r($_GET);` before you do any other code. If it returns `array()` it means the PHP is not receiving the array as a GET request. Then do a `print_r($_REQUEST);` before any other code and see if there is anything received by the PHP script.

Comment: This is what i have in the developer tools :

 Request URL:http://localhost/my-work/internship-work/snippt/create_table.php?col_name=[%22Name%22,%22Age%22,%22DOB%22,%22Residence%22]
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80

And both print_r($_GET) and print_r($_REQUEST) would display the same things : Array()

So the point is why is PHP not receiving the array!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","create_table.php?col_name = "+column_names_json,true);
```

To

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","create_table.php?col_name="+column_names_json,true);
```

You have spaces in your URL string.

**EDIT:**

Change your send process to:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/create_table.php");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(column_names));
```

Then change your PHP script to:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
print_r($json);
```

Comment: It still gives empty Array @Nick Duncan

Comment: Shouldn't `column_names_json` be percent-encoded too? https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump($_GET);`?

Comment: var_dump($_GET) returns : array(0) {} @NickDuncan

Comment: Why did you accept this answer if you're still having problems?

Comment: It didn't solve the answer but it was a mistake so....
But i am really sorry for that..I am new to stack overflow and i was under the impression that since the suggestion was correct i should accept that!!
I am really sorry for that!

Comment: If you uncomment `alert(column_names_json);` what do you get in the alert?

Comment: @NickDuncan That would give me the array in JSON format : ["Name","Age"]

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Since you seem to use JS to read the values and submit through AJAX, the following does not apply. It would only be "true", if you would use the regular form-submit of html.

### Form

You are attaching Elements to `main`, while the form is not sourrounding `main`, thus on submit no data of the added input-elements will be send.

### Browser

You are adding Form-Elements by simply attaching HTML to the already rendered Object-DOM. I've encountered a few browsers which do not allow this.

To handle each and every browser (even if that might not be your core-problem)
you need to modify your javascript, so that the browser actually understands hat a new input-element has been added to a certain form.

rather than

```
document.getElementById('main').innerHTML += '<input     type="text" name = "col" placeholder="column name"> &nbsp;&nbsp; <select>  <option>Integer</option> <option>Varchar</option>  </select><br> <br> ';
```

you need to register the new Element with the browsers DOM, using something like this:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.name = "input_element_x";
referenceToForm.appendChild(input)
```

Some browsers might display "added html", but on submitt only rely on the DOM, which - when using HTML directrly - does not contain your inputs.

Comment: I have incorporated the change you've suggested but i think the problem here is in php file. As far as i know the html file that makes AJAX request is working fine . I've checked that in developer tools tool.Nothing wrong with that @dognode

Comment: @KenilPatel Try to remove `json_decode` from your php-file and see if the raw-data is there. `json_decode` will return `null` if it fails to parse the json-content.

Comment: ok i have removed the json_decode and added : 

if(isset($_GET['col_name'])){
 $arr = $_GET['col_name'];
 print_r($arr);
}
else{
 echo "Something went wrong";
}
This executes the else statement...

Comment: So, data is not send, nothing caused by PHP, but by the javascript you are using for sending data...